# Windows mobile - Zebra Printer mz220

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6, zebra-printers

I am printing to a Zebra printer mz220 via bluetooth from a windows mobile 6 device.  The printing works fine to a point.  After this point the printer pauses and then adds a new line before continuing with it's printing.  This is far from ideal as the pause and new line can happen part way through printing a line that should not have a new line.

I am using the SerialPort class in .net and I have added a thread.sleep(1000) to allow time for all the data that should be printed to get printed.  This fixed an earlier problem where some of the data on long receipts was not being printed.

```
                using (var serialPort = new SerialPort())
            {
                serialPort.PortName = this.PortName;
                serialPort.Open();
                Thread.Sleep(2500);

                serialPort.Write(text);
            }
```

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to go about solving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: this would be a question for the vendor of the printer.

Comment: what is the text you sending to port? It might contain bad command.

Comment: @Daniel - I have tried to contact the vendor and decided I would ask the community while I wait for a response.  You never know someone may have run into the same problem.

Comment: @Renuiz - The text is nothing special.  Characters and dashes to draw a line.  The fact that the pause and line feed don't necessarily happen at the exact same spot would reduce the likleyhood that this is a caused by a bad command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that all I needed to do was to install the Zebra printer SDK and re-write the code against the serial port class provided as part of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Are you printing in line mode, or is this a CPCL format? Are you using continuous media, or label/gap media? Your printer could be incorrectly configured to think it is printing a label (which has gaps in the media) and is skipping over where it thinks the gap is. Look at the:

```
! U1 getvar "media.type"
```

SGD, it should be set to journal if you are using receipt paper and not labels.

```
! U1 setvar "media.type" "journal"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have downloaded the SDK and used their SerialPrinterConnection and a call to WaitForData.  This appears to be working... for now.